# What is the fastest way to copy cds

Tags: compact-disc, external-drive

I have hundreds of legacy cds containing customer account statements. They are currently the backup copies but one year from now they will be the only copy as we are losing the system we use to access them. I need to transfer the contents to disk using a pc, then ultimately to our server for proper archiving. I have a cheap external DVD RW drive that is working very slow in my opinion. I insert disk one, selected all contents of the drive and copy/paste into a directory on the c drive. It goes through the calculating process for 15-20 minutes before it actually starts writing. When it begins writing, it's averaging roughly 4 MB/s. It will take a long time to get this project done at this pace. How can I speed up this process using either my current hardware or something entirely different? We're willing to spend some money if need be as it would pay for itself fairly quick I imagine. Is there hardware/software that would allow us to copy multiple disks at once? Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: If you can find an old CD-RW drive from their golden years (a very long time ago) then maybe that would be faster than a newer DVD-RW drive, but even so, not by much.

Comment: Using the command prompt to do the copy with `XCOPY` or `ROBOCOPY` will be somewhat faster than using the Windows GUI, as neither `XCOPY` nor `ROBOCOPY` will sort the file names, calculate a time estimate, or continually update the display to show progress.

Comment: 4MB/s transfer rate is about what you [can expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-ROM#Transfer_rates) for modern DVD RW drives. The only way to make this faster is multiple drives. Command line tools will work with multiple drivers, and also skip the "calculating process". And you can skript then. CD drivers with automatic loading will allow you unattended copying.

Comment: It wont speed the copy, but you do get "robots" that handle cd's - im sure there are better ones, but something like https://www.primera.com/equipment/disc-publishers.html